# Configuring DyanmoDB read capacity unit for glue job

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

I'm running a glue job to move data from dynamoDB to redshift. Current provisioned RCU of table is 300 and table have about 50GB of data(expected to grow with time). Our normal consumed RCU is near to 100 on an average.   We've configured dynamo to autoscale on 60% consumption of provisioned RCU. Glue job is configured to use 35% of RCU. We can't withstand any impact to production traffic.

With the above configuration in place our job take more than 48hrs to complete. If I increase RCU of dyanmo to 1500 and then run job, it completes in about 8 hrs.

I want to schedule it as a weekly job and hence can't manually update dynamo capacity every time. What are the standard ways to increase dynamo RCU dynamically before glue job runs and decrease after job completes?
Any other way of handling the situation will also be appreciated.

Comment: This is a great question! I would love to know more on the subject. Did you find anything that could help answering your question?

Comment: @Akshansh singh : You could look create a custom script to update the RCU before and after your glue job using the update_table api. Python boto3 api can be found here : https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.update_table